# Implement routing in Sencha Touch 2.4.0

Tags: javascript, extjs, mobile, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to implement routing in Sencha Touch 2.4.0 but am not able to fire a function on route change event. I have a main controller-

```
Ext.define('STPG.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    routes : {
            'home' : 'onHome'
        },

    config: {
        refs: {

        },
        control: {

        }
    },

    //called when the Application is launched, remove if not needed
    launch: function(app) {

    },
    onHome : function() {
        console.log('home controller called');
    }
});
```

app.js

```
views: [
        'Main'
    ],

    models: [],
    controllers: ['Main'],
    stores: [],
```

am trying-

```
Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('STPG.view.Main'));
this.redirectTo('home');
```

Its not calling that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a silly mistake. Just put your `routes: {}` inside `config`. And your problem solved. 
Happy coding!